# Grouping an ordered dataset into minimal number of clusters

Tags: algorithm, list, cluster-analysis

I have an ordered list of weighted items, weight of each is less-or-equal than N.
I need to convert it into a list of clusters.
Each cluster should span several consecutive items, and total weight of a cluster has to be less-or-equal than N.

Is there an algorithm which does it while minimizing the total number of clusters and keeping their weights as even as possible?

E.g. list [(a,5),(b,1),(c,2),(d,5)], N=6 should be converted into [([a],5),([b,c],3),([d],5)]

Comment: yes: put everything into a single cluster. meaning: you'll need some other constraint on the number of clusters.

Comment: You appear to be stating the http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: It's not exactly bin packing, since it has the extra desire to optimize the evenness of distribution (so it's probably harder than bin packing)

Comment: @nicolas78: the problem limits the size of the cluster.

Comment: Bin packing is the best answer so far, thanks. Evenness is a secondary task, and any minimizing solution should be pretty even anyway. The only thing that makes it more complicated is the ORDEREDNESS of original array.

Comment: Maybe you should look for the online version of the algorithm. Online means you have to process items as they come (which will preserve the order).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the dataset is ordered, one possible approach is to assign a "badness" score to each possible cluster and use a dynamic program reminiscent of Knuth's word wrapping ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_wrap ) to minimize the sum of the badness scores. The badness function will let you explore tradeoffs between minimizing the number of clusters (larger constant term) and balancing them (larger penalty for deviating from the average number of items).

Comment: Great, I thought about dynamic programming too. Alas, it seems to be too much of a work for my task, so I think I'm gonna bruteforce it or just approximate.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is under-specified.

The issue is that you are trying to optimize two different properties of the resulting data, and these properties may be in opposition to one another. For a given set of data, it may be that the most even distribution has many clusters, and that the smallest number of clusters has a very uneven distribution.

For example, consider: [(a,1),(b,1),(c,1),(d,1),(e,1)], N=2

The most even distribution is [([a],1),([b],1),([c],1),([d],1),([e],1)]

But the smallest number of clusters is [([a,b],2),([c,d],2),([e],1)]

How is an algorithm supposed to know which of these (or which clustering in between them) you want? You need find some way to *quantify* the tradeoff that you are willing to accept between number of clusters and evenness of distribution.

You can create an example with an arbitrarily large discrepancy between the two possibilities by creating any set with 2k + 1 elements, and assigning them all the value N/2. This will lead to the smallest number of clusters being k+1 clusters (k of 2 elements and 1 of 1) with a weight difference of N/2 between the largest and smallest clusters. And then the most even distribution for this set will be 2k + 1 clusters of 1 element each, with no weight difference.

**Edit:** Also, "evenness" itself is not a well-defined idea. Are you looking to minimize the largest absolute difference in weights between clusters, or the mean difference in weights, or the median difference in weights, or the standard deviation in weights?

Comment: Nopey, these targets are not in contradiction. Optimal solution in your case can clearly be seen, it's [a,b],[c,d], offering both minimal number of clusters and even distribution.

Comment: That's better, but anyway - I think my original question states pretty clearly that minimization is a higher priority.

Comment: Okay, but if you want an answer other than "just use a dynamic program for bin packing", which will end up minimizing clusters and ignoring evenness, you will still have to put the idea of evenness and the relationship between it and minimizing clusters into terms a computer can understand. Your original question is like asking a computer to "produce a picture using as few colors as possible that is as pretty as possible" -- the computer doesn't know what "prettiness" is or how you value prettiness versus number of colors unless you put it in quantifiable terms.

Comment: You are of course correct. There can be some "evenness" metric invented, obvious candidates are "mean square error" or "maximal minimum". But I didn't want to be too specific, since I wanted to hear about all relevant algorithms, and, if there's any, try to adapt it to my goals.